# Маршрутизация 3х сетевых карт

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Доброго времени!

В общем есть 3 сетевухи на шлюзе:

**1 сетевка локалка:**

ip: 10.1.1.2

mask: 255.255.255.0

dns: 10.1.1.2

**2 сетевка VPN от провайдера:**

ip: 172.24.49.74

mask: 255.255.255.248

gw: 172.24.49.73

**3 сетевка INET от того же провадера:**

ip: 80.73.82.98

mask: 255.255.255.252

gw: 80.73.82.97

dns: 80.73.64.251

Шлюз стоит в центральном офисе, по городу есть несколько филиалов. Провайдер подключил услугу L3VPN, выдали IP адреса вида 172.24.49.10-15 + шлюз. Прописываем адреса и шлюзы на филиалах, у себя на шлюзе прописал маршрут:
route add 172.24.49.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.24.49.73 теперь офис и филиалы видят друг друга. Вопрос, как можно завернуть филиалы из 172 сетки еще и в инет? На шлюзе помимо всего прочего стоит керио контрол, создавал правило **VPN интерфейс -> INET интерфейс**, не помогло, как только не изгалялся уже. Плиз хелп.

```
IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      80.73.82.97      80.73.82.98    276
         10.1.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.1.1.2    266
         10.1.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.1.1.2    266
       10.1.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.1.1.2    266
      80.73.82.96  255.255.255.252         On-link       80.73.82.98    276
      80.73.82.98  255.255.255.255         On-link       80.73.82.98    276
      80.73.82.99  255.255.255.255         On-link       80.73.82.98    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      172.24.49.0    255.255.255.0     172.24.49.73     172.24.49.74     21
     172.24.49.72  255.255.255.248         On-link      172.24.49.74    276
     172.24.49.74  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.24.49.74    276
     172.24.49.79  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.24.49.74    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.24.49.74    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       80.73.82.98    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.1.1.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.24.49.74    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       80.73.82.98    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.1.1.2    266
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Сетевой адрес            Маска    Адрес шлюза      Метрика
      172.24.49.0    255.255.255.0     172.24.49.73       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      80.73.82.97  По умолчанию
```

Comment: Настройки неверны. На весь сервер должен быть ОДИН default gateway - в данном случае 80.73.82.97. Все остальные заменить на маршруты в определённые подсети. Теоретически этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы и доступ в Инет у филиалов появился, конечно, при условии, что у них там default gateway отправлен на этот шлюз. *На шлюзе помимо всего прочего стоит керио контрол* нафига он там нужен? У Вас что, шлюз создан на десктопной ОС?

Comment: Основной шлюз для всех сетевок стоит 80.73.82.97, в ручную был прописан шлюз для 172.24.49.0 сетки, т.к. без этого маршрута нет связи с филиалами сети 172.24.49.0 из головного офиса. Керио стоит для контроля доступа к ресурсам интернет офисных сотрудников. Да, на шлюзе стоит windows 7. Я так понимаю, что керио мешает нормально работе маршрутизации и есть какие-то ограничения в десктопной ОС ? Как тогда лучше настроить все это дело? По мимо всего прочего на керио поднят впн сервер для подключения удаленных сотрудников к нашей локальной сети.

Comment: *route print* показывает, что всё нормально по части дефолтных шлюзов. Но есть вопросы по трём маршрутам в узлы 80.73.82.9х - это что за звери? ни один не соответствует исходным данным для интерфейса в Инет. *на шлюзе стоит windows 7* Ну дальше обсуждать в общем нечего - меняйте на нормальную серверную ОС. И там же поднимете VPN-сервер, и снесёте нафиг этот Kerio.

Comment: Честно говоря даже не знаю откуда взялись эти "звери", может керио их создает. Нет пока возможности поставить серверную ОСь, поэтому приходится колхозить на том, что есть, время поджимает в добавок ко всему. А без керио как контролить юзеров?

Comment: Я боюсь у вас проблема не с маршрутизацией, если на филиалах default смотрит в сторону этого шлюза, а в том что вам же еще NAT надо выполнять. Поищите как его на винде делать (по моим наблюдениям на не серверной винде это что то не тривильное, да и на серверной то же)

Comment: Mike, дело в том, что шлюз, который указывается на филиалах это шлюз провайдера(то есть на его оборудовании), я так понял этот шлюз просто не знает о том шлюзе, который у нас для интернета

Comment: Ну я бы тупо посоветовал Вам поменять L3VPN на L2-канал. Тогда филиалы подключатся к вам словно из соседней комнаты. А настройка такой схемы тут - явный неформат. Такие вещи надо решать на форумах.

Comment: Akina, а без крайних методов, как изменение технологии? Деньги то уплочены ))